# convert image hash to python built in int

Tags: python, numpy, hash

I am working on an image hashing project in opencv and python.
I am reading this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/08/26/building-an-image-hashing-search-engine-with-vp-trees-and-opencv/
suppose i converted my image to hash and have **h** as image hash and a 64 bit int :

> h = 5090336880217583642

when i convert **h** to numpy 64-bit float and then convert it to Python’s built-in integer data type like this :

```
h = 5090336880217583642
x = int(np.array(h, dtype="float64"))
print(("x = {} ").format(x))
```

i have **x** in output as :

```
x =5090336880217583616
```

why this happen? why is not **x** equal to **h**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is coming from using float64, you can have a look over [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

you can use:

```
h = 5090336880217583642
x = int(np.array(h, dtype="int64"))
print(("x = {} ").format(x))
```

output:

```
x = 5090336880217583642
```

Comment: thank you @rusru_ro1...

i realized that numpy is approximating the h with some binary fractions and consequently miss some digits of h. is it correct?